# Stop Function From executing after condition is met

Tags: jquery

My html page fires off 2 php scripts, one to perform a task and another to poll a log file and show results on the html page.  After the 'updatestock.php' has finished how do I stop the getStatus() process?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        startProcess();
        getStatus();

    });

    function startProcess() {

      $("#done").load('updatestock.php');

    }

    function getStatus() {

      $("#status").load('getstatus.php');
        setTimeout("getStatus()",2000);

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stopProcess = false;


function startProcess() {

    $("#done").load('updatestock.php', function() {

        stopProcess  = true;

    });

}

function getStatus() {

    if ( stopProcess){
        return false;
    }

    $("#status").load('getstatus.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",2000);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use clearTimeout:

```
// persistent variable needed
var timeout = 0;
$(function() {
    startProcess();
    getStatus();

});

function startProcess() {
  // second parameter of load = completion callback
  $("#done").load('updatestock.php',function()
  { 
      // clearTimeout will stop the next getStatus from firing.
      clearTimeout(timeout); 
      timeout = -1;
  });

}

function getStatus() {
  // just in case. You never know what's cached.
  // (the ids for setTimeout are positive).
  if( timeout < 0 ) return; 
  $("#status").load('getstatus.php');
  // sets the ID of the current timeout.
  timeout = setTimeout("getStatus()",2000);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the callback from the `load()` method to set a flag and then check for it in your `getStatus()` method:

```
$(function() {
    startProcess();
    getStatus();

    var flag = false;
});

function startProcess() {

    $("#done").load('updatestock.php', function() {

        flag = true;

    });

}

function getStatus() {

    if ( flag ) return false;

    $("#status").load('getstatus.php');
    setTimeout("getStatus()",2000);

}
```

Comment: This code didnt fire the getStatus function until I moved ' var flag = false;' to the outside of function's {}

Answer (score 0):

Put the delayed call to `getStatus` in the callback for `load`, and use an if statement that determines whether to call it or not based on what getstatus.php returns. It could be a certain response code or bit of data, e.g. `"finished": true` in a JSON response.